# How can I automate the production of multiple nets in igraph?

Tags: r, for-loop, igraph

I have some data that I am going to be using in igraph. There are two dataframes for each sample: one with a list of links and the other with a list of nodes. Igraph uses these dataframes to produce a net eg.:

```
net1 <- graph_from_data_frame(d=sample1links, vertices=sample1nodes)
```

where `sample1links` and `sample1nodes` are different dataframes.

I have lots of different samples so it would be good if I could automate this process. Is there a method that I can use that will do the process above to produce all of the nets for the samples (i.e. net1-netn, where n is the number of samples)?

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help!!

Comment: You can try to put all sample dfs in a list, then use `sapply()` or `Map()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how I would tell R to link sample1links to sample1nodes, sample2links to sample2nodes and so on in sapply or Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
library(igraph)

# 2 example graphs as data frames
sample1nodes <- read.table(text = "a\nb\n\nc\nd\ne")
sample1links <- read.table(text = "a c\n\nb c\nc d")
sample2nodes <- read.table(text = "A\nB\n\nc\nd\ne")
sample2links <- read.table(text = "A c\n\nB c\nc d")

# create igraph objects from data frames in a list
glst <- Map(graph_from_data_frame, d=mget(ls(pattern = "sample\\d+links")), vertices=mget(ls(pattern = "sample\\d+nodes")))
names(glst) <- paste0("net", sub("sample(\\d+)links", "\\1", names(glst))) # rename list objects

# Store list elements in the global environment under their names
list2env(glst, envir = .GlobalEnv)

# plot
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(net1)
plot(net2)
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for that. I only have one question, so  at the moment that works really well, but only up to sample9. Once the samples are in double figures it doesn't work anymore. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Oops, yea you are right - the regular expression has got to be `pattern = "sample\\d+links"`, not `pattern = "sample\\dlinks"`

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for that!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the question as solved (=tick check mark) if the answer is what you looked for.